# SRTM DEM and satellite DEM fusion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, remote-sensing

I have a SRTM DEM and a DEM derived from satellite (Cartosat). Both the DEMs are registered perfectly. Now I want to carry out a DEM 'fusion' process to derive a higher quality output DEM.

I am not using the fusion software. The two dems are not having any holes. I need tools to fuse two DEMS to generate a better quality DEM. (Weighted averaging, sparse representation or frequency based filtering )

I want to carry out in arc gis.

Comment: Are you just trying to average the two DEMs together? Fill holes in one with the other? Mosaic areas of different coverage? Please note the tag Fusion refers to a specific piece of software used for working with LiDAR data. Is that what you are using, and if not what software *are* you using?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for raster tools. This could be done with a simple raster calculation (`(r1+r2)/2`), or throw a weight into it, or with more advanced raster tools that could do filtering, etc. We have some questions here on the subject in which answers suggest various methods and software alternatives. You might take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=average+two+dems or just http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+dems Unless you can specify a software you need to use or a specific method that must be followed, this question might be too broad for GIS.SE.

Comment: Do you have access to Spatial Analyst? That is required for all but the most basic of raster operations.

Comment: yes I have access to spatial analyst. Idont mind using other softwares like grass or quantum gis

Answer (score 1):

1. Add both DEMS together and divide by 2 in the Raster Calculator. `(RAS1 + RAS2)*.5
2. Fill holes in A with B or fill holes in B with A.
3. Use a combination of low pass and high pass filters in a method proposed by Karkee, Manoj, Brian L. Steward, and Samsuzana Abd Aziz. "Improving quality of public domain digital elevation models through data fusion." biosystems engineering 101.3 (2008): 293-305. it is quite straightforward.
4. Use a mapping of residuals approach as suggested by Papasaika, H., D. Poli, and E. Baltsavias. "A framework for the fusion of digital elevation models." Int Arch Photogramm Remote Sens Spatial Inf Sci 37.B2 (2008): 811-817.

All links are to open access articles.